# How to convert multicharacter single line into string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, line, readfile

Hello I have line like below in a file

```
I want to convert Text :0 to 8978 as a single string. And same for other part i.e Text:1 to 8978. 

Text:0
6786993cc89 70hgsksgoop 869368
7897909086h fhsi799hjdkdh 099h
Gsjdh768hhsj dg9978hhjh98 8978

Text:1
8786993cc89 70hgsksgoop 869368
7897909086h fhsi799hjdkdh 099h
Gsjdh768hhsj dg9978hhjh98 8978
```

```
I am getting output as 
6 
7
G

8
7
G
```

But i want output as from string one and from string two as

6
8

Code is :

file = open ('tem.txt','r')
lines = file.readlines()
print(lines)
for line in lines:
line=line.strip()
linex=line.replace(' ','')
print(linex)
print (linex[0])

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add your code, please.

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: Hello everyone. I am reading a file which has this kind of data. But he is not treating as single string he is treating as single line

Comment: Instead of repeating the (unclear) question, clear up the question itself. There are no "lines" in Python, only strings. The `line` variable contains a single string, so your actual question is already answered. Your desired output is just the first character in the file. Is that what you really want? Or did you want to display the first part of each line? Or perhaps combine all first parts into a single string? What about the other parts?

Comment: If you wanted to read a comma or space delimited file and process the individual fields, you could use any CSV library using space as the delimiter

Comment: I want to display the first few indices of each part

Comment: Also if you suggest how to combine first part as a whole string and same for other parts that will be very helpful.

Comment: I want to make a combine string of part one. Then combine string of part 2 and so on...

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your issue is? *Why* is ``6`` the correct output but ``6`` ``7`` ``G`` is not – what's the desired logic behind that? Are you aware that you do convert *each* single line properly, but do it for all lines one after the other? Why don't you stop after the first line?

Comment: I am not saying 6 7 G is not correct output. According to my code they are correct. But i want to read the whole part (i.e.Text:0) as a single string. So I can get output as 6. And similarly for other part as well

Comment: So your actual question is how to split at the "blocks", i.e. read everything from ``Text:`` to ``8978`` as one string and the next as another string?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want from Text: to 8978 as one string and same for other part

Comment: You should [edit] your question then. This requirement is not at all apparent from the question text.

Comment: Ok. Then what should I edit in the question part? Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what exact do you need, so:

**#1.** If need only print the first number (6), I think your code is right.

**#2.** If you need to print the first part of string(before "space"), it can help you:

```
line="6786993cc8970hgsksgoop869368 7897909086hfhsi799hjdkdh099h Gsjdh768hhsjdg9978hhjh988978"
print(line[0])
print(line.split(' ')[0])
```

**EDIT**

To read a file....

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
Lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

for line in Lines:
    print(line.split(' ')[0])
```

**New EDIT**

First you need to format your file to after that get the first element. Try this please:

```
file = open ('tem.txt','r')
    lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

linesArray = []
lineTemp = ""
for line in lines:
    if 'Text' in line:
        if lineTemp:
          linesArray.append(lineTemp)
          lineTemp = ""
    else:
        lineTemp += line.strip()
linesArray.append(lineTemp)

for newline in linesArray:
    print(newline.split(' ')[0][0])
```

Comment: I have file from where I am reading the data

Comment: To be sure, "Text:0" and "Text:1" exists in your file? I'm asking you to understand well your real file.

Comment: Yes. They exist in my file till Text:100

Comment: But for example purpose I posted till text:1

Comment: Check my new edit please

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Almost getting the desired output. But its repetative.
6
6
6
6
6
8
8
8
like this

Comment: I used your example as input file, are you sure it's ok? if possible upload a example file in some place to we test with real data.

Comment: linesArray.append(lineTemp)   the indentation of this line is correct in your code?  after else

Comment: Yes, it's at same level of "for", not inside "if"

Answer (score 0):

This should work only if you want to view the first character. Essentially, this code will read your text file, convert multiple lines in the text file to one single string and print out the required first character.

```
with open(r'tem.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    line = ''.join(data)
    print(line[0])
```

**EDITED RESPONSE**

Try using regex. Hope this helps.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(Text:[0-9]+\s)+') 

with open(r'tem.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data = [i for i in data if len(i.strip())>0]
    line = ' '.join([i.strip() for i in data if len(i)>0]).strip()
    occurences = re.findall(pattern, line)
    for i in occurences:
        match_i = re.search(i, line)
        start = match_i.end()
        print(line[start])
```

Comment: Thank you. But i want to read first character of every part.

Comment: ok. please check my edited response for your problem.

Comment: its work. for data which i shared. But its not working for below 
"""
Packet: Id:0 Timing:1890
189huebhbh huebhbhefj8klo0985hi  782h678yuh //32
289huebhbh huebhbhefj8klo0985hi7 82h678yuh //62
364huebhbh huebhbhefj 8klo0985hi 782h678yuh //128
89huebhbh  huebhbhefj 8klo0985hi 782h678yuh //235
"""
Ankit: Id:1 Timing:1890
189huebhbh huebhbhefj8klo0985hi782h678yuh //32
289huebhbh huebhbhefj8klo0985hi782h678yuh //62
364huebhbh huebhbhefj 8klo0985hi 782h678yuh //128
89huebhbh  huebhbhefj 8klo0985hi 782h678yuh //235
789huebhbh huebhbhefj 8klo0985hi 782h678yuh //326